# Copying and then resuming an AWS EC2 instance that's holding specific applications

Tags: amazon-web-services

To save money, I now want to temporarily remove my Amazon EC2 instance that's holding different applications of mine (for now, I don't need to be in "production mode" anymore). However, in the future, I want to use these very same applications (as they are now) again when I decide to resume "production mode".

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Just shut it down - **Stop the instance**. You won't be charged for the EC2 time while the instance is stopped.

You will still be charged for EBS volumes storage though. The price depends on the storage type (https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/) and to save some more you can convert the EBS volume to `sc1` type which is the cheapest (albeit the slowest too).

Alternatively you can *Create image* (=AMI) from the instance and pay the "Snapshot price per GB" as described in the above link. That's cheaper than SSD (`gp2`) storage but more expensive than `sc1` storage.

Also note that up to 30GB of storage is covered by the *Free tier* - you can use that without paying.

Hope that helps :)